# In F#, is it possible to pass a reference to a mutable, defaulted value as a parameter?

Tags: f#, mutable

For the [Froto](https://github.com/ctaggart/froto) project (Google Protobuf in F#), I am trying to update the deserialization code from using `'a ref` objects to passing values `byref<'a>`, for performance.

However, the code below fails on the `hydrator &element field` line:

```
type Field = TypeA | TypeB | Etc

let hydrateRepeated
        (hydrator:byref<'a> -> Field -> unit)
        (result:byref<'a list>)
        (field:Field) =
    let mutable element = Unchecked.defaultof<'a>
    hydrator &element field
    result <- element :: result
```

> error FS0421: The address of the variable 'element' cannot be used at this point

Is there anything I can do to get this code to work without changing the signature of the `hydrator` parameter?

I'm very aware that I could use `hydrator:'a ref -> Field -> unit` and get things to work.  However, the goal is to support deserializing into `record` types without needing to create a bunch of `ref` objects on the heap every time a record is deserialize.

Note that the following code is perfectly legal and has the same signature as the `hydrator` function declaration, above, so I'm unclear on what the problem is.

```
let assign (result:byref<'a>) (x:'a) =
    result <- x

let thisWorks() =
    let mutable v = Unchecked.defaultof<int>
    assign &v 5
    printfn "%A" v
```

Comment: I think it's a compiler bug that the signature for `hydrator` is even allowed.  You can't have a `byref<_>` as part of an F# function type, since at the CLR level that would require something akin to an `FSharpFunc<byref<'a>, ...>` and `byref`s aren't valid type arguments.

Comment: What you should do is create a new delegate type which takes a byref argument and use that instead (something like `type byrefAction<'a,'b> = delegate of byref<'a> * 'b -> unit` and then `hydrator:byrefAction<'a,Field>`).  Then there's no need to resort to `ref`.

Comment: Regarding the compiler's erroneous behavior, see https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/819 for a collection of somewhat related issues.

Comment: I don't suppose there is any way to inline hydrator?

Comment: @kvb (see edited question) It appears to be perfectly legal to create a function with a byref parameter, so I am confused as to why it is not legal to pass such a function as a parameter.

Comment: @mydogisbox There are about a dozen hydrator functions, and some are inline.  However, I'm not sure how that would help in this case.  Do you have a working code example?

Comment: @kvb The delegate solution looks like it will work, but requires tupled arguments for all my hydration functions.  Can you recall if the F# compiler optimizes away the tuple in such a case?  Also, I presume the Invoke call on the delegate is more expensive than calling a function parameter, but I'm also presuming the cost of lots of little heap allocations for a bunch of refs would be worse...

Comment: I was wondering if it was inlined if it might optimize the extra allocation away

Comment: @mydogisbox Possibly, but that sidesteps the question :-)  I'd like to know for cases where I don't want to inline.  Would prefer not to inline these, as the code generation side would be bigger for only a small amount of performance gain (though I should measure & test, test & measure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll try to clarify what I was saying in my comments.  You're right that your definition of `assign` is perfectly fine, and it *appears* to have the signature `byref<'a> -> 'a -> unit`.  However, if you look at the resulting assembly, you'll find that the way it's compiled at the .NET representation level is:

```
Void assign[a](a ByRef, a)
```

(that is, it's a method that takes two arguments and doesn't return anything, not a function value that takes one argument and returns a function that takes the next argument and returns a value of type `unit` - the compiler uses some additional metadata to determine how the method was actually declared).

The same is true of function definitions that don't involve `byref`.  For instance, assume you've got the following definition:

```
let someFunc (x:int) (y:string) = ()
```

Then the compiler actually creates a method with the signature

```
Void someFunc(Int32, System.String)
```

The compiler is smart enough to do the right thing when you try to use a function like `someFunc` as a first class value - if you use it in a context where it isn't applied to any arguments, the compiler will generate a subtype of `int -> string -> unit` (which is `FSharpFunc<int, FSharpFunc<string, unit>>` at the .NET representation level), and everything works seamlessly.

However, if you try to do the same thing with `assign`, it won't work (or shouldn't work, but there are several compiler bugs that may make it seem like certain variations work when really they don't - you might not get a compiler error but you may get an output assembly that is malformed instead) - it's not legal for .NET type instantiations to use `byref` types as generic type arguments, so `FSharpFunc<int byref, FSharpFunc<int, unit>>` is not a valid .NET type.  The fundamental way that F# represents function values just doesn't work when there are `byref` arguments.

So the workaround is to create your own type with a method taking a `byref` argument and then create subtypes/instances that have the behavior you want, sort of like doing manually what the compiler does automatically in the non-`byref` case.  You could do this with a named type

```
type MyByrefFunc2<'a,'b> =
    abstract Invoke : 'a byref * 'b -> unit

let assign = {
    new MyByrefFunc2<_,_> with 
        member this.Invoke(result, x) = 
            result <- x }
```

or with a delegate type

```
type MyByrefDelegate2<'a,'b> = delegate of 'a byref * 'b -> unit

let assign = MyByrefDelegate2(fun result x -> result <- x)
```

Note that when calling methods like `Invoke` on the delegate or nominal type, no actual tuple is created, so you shouldn't be concerned about any extra overhead there (it's a .NET method that takes two arguments and is treated as such by the compiler).  There is the cost of a virtual method call or delegate call, but in most cases similar costs exist when using function values in a first class way too.  And in general, if you're worried about performance then you should set a target and measure against it rather than trying to optimize prematurely.